# The same repository for several BLoCs in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

Is it a good idea to use the same repository for several BLoCs?

Comment: It's certainly better than duplicating the code if both BLoCs need it. Other than that, we would probably need more information.

Comment: As with so many things, the answer is: it depends.

Comment: I have just discovered an [issue on Github](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/2436#issuecomment-830993494) related to this topic where the maintainer of the BLOC package tells some best practices. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a broad question to be asked well according to me, using the same repository for many `BLoCs` in Flutter is typically not advised.

A `repository` should be created to fulfil the data requirements of a particular feature or module inside your project as it is often responsible for maintaining a specific data source or `API`. The architecture of your project will be more flexible and modular if each `BLoC` has its own `repository` instance.

You may make sure that the data requirements for each feature are distinct and well-defined by utilising different `repositories` for each `BLoC`. This makes it simpler to test and maintain your code. Also, it enables you to alter one aspect without altering others.

A common `repository`, however, could be appropriate in some circumstances, such as when several features rely on the same data source or when the data is straightforward and doesn't need its own repository. In these situations, it's crucial to carefully weigh the trade-offs and make sure the `shared repository` is created in a way that satisfies the requirements of all the features that depend on it.